# Stable complement of a linear space wrt to a diagonalizable operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $h$ be a semisimple (diagonalizable) linear operator on a vector space $V$, and let $W$ be a subspace of $V$. Is it true that we can always find a direct complement $U$ of $W$ in $V$ that is $h$ stable? In other words, does there always exist $V = U\oplus W$ such that $h(U)\subset U$? What if $V$ is finite dimensional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely true for finite-dimensional spaces: then $V$ has a basis $B$ of eigenvectors of $h$.

Now choose any basis of $W$, extend the basis of $W$ with vectors taken from $B$. This will yield a subspace $U$ with $V=W\oplus U$. Moreover, $U$ is $h$-invariant, $h(U)\subset U$.

Comment: Why is that it is possible to extend the basis of $W$ with vectors taken from $B$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma